# Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given

Tags: php, mysql

I cant seem to figure out what I'am doing wrong. So when I submit my form I get Warning error and the

> Notice: Undefined variable: dbusername in /Library/WebServer/Documents/ArturoLuna_Final/loginCheck.php on line 30

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password']; 

if($username&&$password)
{
    require 'conn.php';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM  users WHERE username='$username'";
    $result = $mysql->query($query) or die(mysqli_error($mysql));
    $numrows = $result->num_rows;
    
    if ($numrows!=0)
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        { 
            $dbusername = $row['username'];
            $dbpassword = $row['password']; 
        }

        //check to see if they match!
        if($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword)
        { 
            echo "youre In!";
        }
        else
        echo "incorrect password!";
        
    }
    else
        die("that user is dead");
    
    //echo $numrows;
    
}

else

    echo ("Please Enter Username")
```

what can I be possibly doing wrong?

Comment: again, which line is line 30?

Comment: BE AWARE: You do not Escape the Username before sending him to the Database... Read about "SQLinjection".

Comment: you should look into using prepared statements

Answer (score 14):

Change

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

to

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
```

You missed an `i` off the function name, and mixed up OO and procedural style code, so you are mixing up `mysql_*` result resources and `mysqli_result` objects.

Answer (score 7):

You're mixing traditional PHP MySQL functions `mysql_*` with the MySQLi interface. In this case, `mysql_fetch_assoc()` expects a resource handle created with `mysql_query()`.

To retrieve the correct result, you'll need to use MySQLi's method:

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

And while you're at it, you might want to consider making the code less susceptible to MySQL injection. [Properly escape](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) *any user provided input* before interpolating it into a query string, or better yet, use MySQLi [parameter binding facilities](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).